# Expandable recyclerview and firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, expand

I'm using expandable recyclerview library ([this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)) and for populate this recyclerview I'm using firebase backend service. I use this expandable recyclerview to show chat users and it works. But my problem is, when some people change online status from online to offline state and vice versa my recyclerview refresh and all the groups that were expanded after the change of the online status collapsed.

My code:

ViewHolder

GroupHolder

```
public class ClubNameViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

View view;
TextView clubName2;
CircleImageView clubLogoImg;
TextView onlineTexview;
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

public ClubNameViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    view = itemView;
    clubName2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clubName_Users);
    clubLogoImg = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_club_logo);
    onlineTexview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_online_text);
}

public void setClubTitle(ExpandableGroup club) {
    if (club instanceof UserChatGroup) {
        clubName2.setText(club.getTitle());

        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(((UserChatGroup) club).getClubLogo()).into(clubLogoImg);
        onlineTexview.setText(((UserChatGroup) club).getOnline());
    }

}
}
```

ChildHolder

```
public class UsersChatViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

View view;
TextView usernameUser;
CircleImageView flagUser;
CircleImageView profileImageUser;
ImageView onlineImage;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

public UsersChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    view = itemView;
    usernameUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameUsers);
    flagUser = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagUsers);
    profileImageUser = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileUsers);
    onlineImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.onlineStatus);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void setOnlineImage(){
    Log.i("online", String.valueOf(MainPage.myClubName));
    Log.i("online", String.valueOf(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()));
    final DatabaseReference onlineReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersChat").child(MainPage.myClubName).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    onlineReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean isOnline = (boolean) dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue();
            Log.i("online", String.valueOf(isOnline));

            if (isOnline){
                onlineImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                onlineImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void setUsername (String username){
    usernameUser.setText(username);
}

public void setFlag(Context ctx, String flag){

    GenericRequestBuilder<Uri, InputStream, SVG, PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;

    requestBuilder = Glide
            .with(ctx)
            .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, ctx), InputStream.class)
            .from(Uri.class)
            .as(SVG.class)
            .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
            .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
            .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SearchableCountry.SvgDecoder()))
            .decoder(new SearchableCountry.SvgDecoder())
            .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in);


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(flag);
    requestBuilder
            // SVG cannot be serialized so it's not worth to cache it
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .load(uri)
            .into(flagUser);

}

public void setProfileImage(Context ctx, String proifleImage){
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(proifleImage).into(profileImageUser);
}
}
```

Model

UsersModel

```
public class UserChat {

String username;
String flag;
String profileImage;

public UserChat(String username, String flag, String profileImage) {
    this.username = username;
    this.flag = flag;
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFlag() {
    return flag;
}

public void setFlag(String flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

public String getProfileImage() {
    return profileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}
}
```

Group model

```
public class UserChatGroup extends ExpandableGroup {
String clubLogo;
String online;
public UserChatGroup(String title, List items,String clubLogo,String online) {
    super(title, items);

    this.clubLogo = clubLogo;
    this.online = online;
}

public String getClubLogo() {
    return clubLogo;
}

public void setClubLogo(String clubLogo) {
    this.clubLogo = clubLogo;
}

public String getOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void setOnline(String online) {
    this.online = online;
}


}
```

Adapter

```
public class ClubNameChatAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<ClubNameViewHolder, UsersChatViewHolder> {
Context ctx;

public ClubNameChatAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups, Context ctx) {
    super(groups);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public ClubNameViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.parent_layout_users, parent, false);

    return new ClubNameViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public UsersChatViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_layout_users, parent, false);

    return new UsersChatViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(UsersChatViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {

    UserChat userChat = (UserChat) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
    holder.setUsername(userChat.getUsername());
    holder.setFlag(ctx, userChat.getFlag());
    holder.setProfileImage(ctx, userChat.getProfileImage());
    holder.setOnlineImage();

}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(ClubNameViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,     ExpandableGroup group) {
    holder.setClubTitle(group);
}
}
```

Fragment

```
public class FragmentChatUsers extends Fragment {

RecyclerView userRecylerView;
ClubNameChatAdapter adapter;
List<UserChatGroup> clubName;
DatabaseReference userReference;
String profileImage;
String username;
String flag;
String clubNameLogo;
boolean isOnline;
int numberOnline;
String online;


public void getClubName() {
    userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersChat");

    userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            clubName = new ArrayList<UserChatGroup>();
            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                final String clubNameString = snapshot.getKey().toString();

                DatabaseReference chatReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersChat").child(clubNameString);
                chatReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        final List<UserChat> userChats = new ArrayList<UserChat>();
                        numberOnline = 0;
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            username = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("username").getValue());
                            profileImage = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("profileImage").getValue());
                            flag = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("flag").getValue());
                            clubNameLogo = String.valueOf(snapshot1.child("favoriteClubLogo").getValue());
                            isOnline = (boolean) snapshot1.child("online").getValue();

                            if (isOnline){
                                numberOnline++;
                            }

                            online = String.valueOf(numberOnline);



                            userChats.add(new UserChat(username, flag, profileImage));
                        }
                            clubName.add(new UserChatGroup(clubNameString, userChats, clubNameLogo, online));


                        adapter = new ClubNameChatAdapter(clubName, getContext());
                        userRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                        userRecylerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    DatabaseReference setOfline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersChat").child(MainPage.myClubName).child(MainPage.uid);
    setOfline.child("online").setValue(true);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    DatabaseReference setOfline = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersChat").child(MainPage.myClubName).child(MainPage.uid);
    setOfline.child("online").setValue(false);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_users,container,false);

    userRecylerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.chatUserRecView);
    getClubName();

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, change addValueEventListener in addListenerForSingleValueEvent